# html5でカメラが起動しない(android)

Tags: android, monaca, iphone, html5, camera

monacaを使用して、html5でカメラが動くアプリを作っています。

スマホにビルド・インストールし、iphoneではボタンをタップするとカメラが起動するのですが、androidの場合カメラでなくスマホのローカルフォルダが参照される状況になっており、androidでもカメラが起動するようにしたいのですが、調べても解決出来ない状況です。どのようにしたらandroidでもカメラを起動出来ますでしょうか？

Comment: <input type="file" name="my_img" id="my_img" accept="accept="image/*;capture=camera">
←のコードです

Comment: スマホでchromeを使用して、ブラウザから実行するとカメラが起動するのですが、アプリ化するとスマホのローカルフォルダの選択画面しか出てこないです。